# How to style React component after importing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I did some research but also **I didn't find a proper answer**

```
import Card from "./components/Card/card";

class CardCollection extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card />
        <Card />
        <Card />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardCollection;
```

How do I style** those **Card components?**

**I tried:**

```
     <div className="class-name1"> <Card /> </div>
     <div className="class-name2"> <Card /> </div>
     <div className="class-name3"> <Card /> </div>
```

But I think it's not the good way to do it.
Neither this

```
<Card propName="margin-tb-20" />
<Card propName="margin-tb-20" />
<Card propName="margin-tb-20" />
<Card propName="margin-tb-20" />
<Card propName="margin-tb-20" />
```

Even doing this by using the loop does not look good for me. So is there any **alternative?**

Comment: There are any numbers of ways to style react components. `className`, inline-style-prop, some other theming library/module. It's really up to you to decide which to use. In your example, however, you are styling the containing div, not the `Card`.

Comment: You can pass className to the Card component and in the card component you need to inject this className as well. So the component usage will look like: `<Card className="" />`

Comment: Allow Card component to accept a custom classname as prop and pass it on to it while rendering in parent

Comment: Lets us suppose i need to use 3 card: <Card className="smt-className" /> might look good but I need to do it for multiple times. So is there any alternative or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eways to do it:

1- via passing inline style:
a: `<Card style={{color:"red"}} />`
b: inside of card comp you can use it like:

```
<div style={this.props.style}>
```

2- by class name:
a: `<Card cssClassName="c1" />`
b: use it on every element inside of card like example:

```
<div className={this.props.cssClasName}>
```

note that if Card comp is a component that you import from a library you should read it's document instead, normally they implemented both ways

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must provide component name capitalized:

```
cardCollection // Rename it to CardCollection
```

Now, to your query; you can provide props to the component:

```
<Card className="class-name1" />
```

And in the Card component, you can provide the props:

```
{/* card */}
<div {...props}>
```

Comment: I did this, but while doing so it just looks like a styling component using className not actually staying component like elements. 

In my condition, I need to render 18 cards component, and writing something like ''' <Card marginFixer="m-tp-20" /> '''  for 18times is a bad idea. So I was looking alternative :)